# Are Ability Score Increases the same across all classes?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, character-levels

I did some quick research through the players handbook and it seemed like all classes gained ability score increase at 4th, 8th, 12th, 16th, and 19th levels.

I only did this for a few classes but is it correct to assume this is the same for all classes in the game?

Also, are the points to be added always the same? For all the classes I saw they got 2 points they could add per level that pertains to that addition. Is that the same for all classes?

Comment: if you downvote, please comment with the reason

Comment: I just downvoted: "lack of research" is one of the reasons given when hovering over the downvote button, and it's the reason I did. (There are only twelve classes, so if you've looked at a few there are only eight or nine more to glance at.)

Comment: I personally downvoted because in the time it took you to write and post this question, you could have simply read the ASI section for the other classes. It shows a distinct lack of effort. You already read "a few"; why not just read the others?

Comment: I answered it on the basis that having the info in one spot as a comparison might serve some useful purpose. I agree however, that the research consisted of doing exactly as Baron commented.

Comment: @nitsua60 thank you for adding your reason.  I did a quick check and thought it would be more time efficient for me to ask on a forum like this where the breadth of knowledge could provide even more info than the question originally posited as is displayed by the answers. e.g. barbarians ASI caps mentioned by both answers and the replacement of ASI for feats also mentioned by both answers. I would have been oblivious to such details had I simply done what you suggest

Comment: @keithcurtis Thank you for your reason. I will take yours and Barons words into consideration as I post further on this board. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi W.Harr. Just a few things to help you on your way here at rpg.se. Consider taking the [tour] as it's a useful introduction to the site and checking out the [help] for a bit more information. Most importantly is that RPG StackExchange is a Q&A site, not a forum. Also, even though it may be helpful [users aren't required to explain their downvotes](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/can-we-require-comments-on-downvotes).

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Thank you for the references you've provided. In response to your last sentence, I agree with the answer provided in the link you provided. The reason I commented for answers was because I wanted constructive criticism on how to ask better questions on the site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Fighter class gets Ability Score Increases at **4, 6 ,8, 12, 14 16, and 19**. That's **7 ASIs** or two more than most other classes.

Barbarians also work slightly differently from other classes in that they have the same progression of ASIs as most other characters, but have a capstone feature at level 20 called Primal Champion, that grants them a +4 in Strength and Constitution, increasing their maximum potential score in each ability to 24. This is not the same as a normal Ability Score Increase, in that it is not listed in the Ability Score Increase feature, which otherwise limits them to 20 in all abilities. Because this capstone feature is not an ASI, they cannot use it to gain a feat, if the campaign uses that optional rule.

The **Rogue** class gains Ability Score Increases at **4, 8, 10, 12, 16 and 19** for a total of **6 ASIs**.

All other classes follow the  **4, 8, 12, 16, 19** pattern for **5 ASIs**.

In all cases, an Ability Score Increase lets you add 1 to two different ability scores, or 2 to a single ability score. If using feats, the ASI can be used to add a feat instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to add clarity to your answer

Answer (score 9):

### Rogues and Fighters get additional Ability Score Increases.

Most classes receive an Ability Score Increase on 4th, 8th, 12th, 16th, and 19th level. However, there are two exceptions:

- Rogues receive an ASI on 4th, 8th, **10th**, 12th, 16th, and 19th.
- Fighters receive an ASI on 4th, **6th**, 8th, 12th, **14th**, 16th, and 19th.

### All class-based Ability Score Increases are two points.

Any ASI received from leveling up will be two points, or picking a feat from the available feats if your DM allows.

Some classes receive additional ability score bonuses as part of leveling up. For example, Barbarians receive a flat increase of 4 to both Strength and Constitution upon hitting 20th level, simultaneously increasing the maximum value for these scores from 20 to 24.

Comment: You write "for example". Is there another example than the level 20 Barbarian?

Comment: @MarsPlastic To my knowledge, currently, no. I wrote it that way as future-proofing against later books and additions to 5e.